# SQL Subquery of Join - concatenation based index to be filtered by max date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am relatively new to SQL - having only started using it in the last week. I am having some trouble joining 2 tables together by concatenation based indexes (which I can do but it shows up with several dates) and then filtering it by max date

Please see below for the first version that shows the tables joined together.
There are two tables which I need to join.
INVENTORY_TRANSACTION_HIST2 (the job)
inventory_transaction_hist (further details related to the item specifics)

there are no related between these tables so I have had to build concatenated ones from several fields:
`part_no||lot_batch_no||serial_no||location_no`
is for relating between the two tables.

`order_no||release_no||sequence_no||line_item_no`
relates only to the second table and creates the required index for filtering the date

```
select
to_char(job.dated,'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss') date_issued,
job.userid,
job.part_no,
job.quantity,
job.lot_batch_no,
job.serial_no,
job.cost,
job.quantity* job.cost total_cost,
job.source note,
hist.dated,
hist.order_no,
hist.release_no,
hist.sequence_no,
hist.line_item_no

from
inventory_transaction_job job
left join inventory_transaction_hist hist
on job.part_no||job.lot_batch_no||job.serial_no||job.location_no = hist.part_no||hist.lot_batch_no||hist.serial_no||hist.location_no
where (job.source like UPPER('%'||'&Job_No'||'%') or job.source like LOWER('%'||'&Job_No'||'%'))
and hist.transaction LIKE '%INM-IN%'
and hist.direction LIKE '+'
order by job.part_no
```

I need to further split this by the most recent date on the hist. table (as some batch / serial numbers are just shown as '*' so can show several order numbers against each - I want to just show the most recent order for these)

I have tried the below and a few other variations but I can't seem to get it working.

```
select
to_char(job.dated,'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss') date_issued,
job.userid user_id,
job.part_no,
job.quantity,
job.lot_batch_no,
job.serial_no,
job.cost,
job.quantity* job.cost total_cost,
job.source note,
hist.dated,
hist.order_no,
hist.release_no,
hist.sequence_no,
hist.line_item_no

from
inventory_transaction_job job
left join inventory_transaction_hist hist
on job.part_no||job.lot_batch_no||job.serial_no||job.location_no = hist.part_no||hist.lot_batch_no||hist.serial_no||hist.location_no
where (job.source like UPPER('%'||'&Job_No'||'%') or job.source like LOWER('%'||'&Job_No'||'%'))
and hist.transaction LIKE '%INM-IN%'
and hist.direction LIKE '+'
and job.order_no||job.sequence_no||job.line_item_no IN
(SELECT
hist2.order_no||hist2.sequence_no||hist2.line_item_no
FROM inventory_transaction_hist hist2
WHERE job.part_no||job.lot_batch_no||job.serial_no||job.location_no LIKE hist2.part_no||hist2.lot_batch_no||hist2.serial_no||hist2.location_no
ORDER BY hist2.Dated DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to concatenate strings together for your join - you can use `AND` and `OR` to have the tables join via multiple columns. For example `JOIN hist ON (job.part_no = hist.part_no AND job...` etc.

Comment: I think we may need to see some example data and output.  And yeah, use logical comparisons, not concatenation - depending on what your datatypes are, that isn't even safe.  Also, convert the contents of `job.source` to either upper or lower case, and remove one of the functions.  You're also probably better off returning `job.dated` (`job.occurred` may be a better name) as a timestamp, for the display software to deal with.  A `LIKE` clause with only one character is equivalent to using `=`, did you mean to add wildcards?

Comment: Thank you for your input! It makes a lot of sense now that you mention it not to use concatenations in such a way! That's a good idea, it would be more suitable to differentiate the date as an occurrance. Oops yes, i did just mean to use = not LIKE

Answer (score 0):

First, as mentioned in a comment, you should do joins on the individual columns connected by "ands" rather than trying to concatenate them together.  The concatenation is clever, but it makes it much harder for the query optimizer to do its job, for instance.

I got the idea that you want the most recent date from the history table for different groups.  I calculate the max date using an analytic function, and then use that for the comparison.

The final query looks like this:

```
select to_char(job.dated,'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss') date_issued, job.userid user_id, job.part_no,
        job.quantity, job.lot_batch_no, job.serial_no, job.cost, job.quantity* job.cost total_cost,
        job.source note, hist.dated,  hist.order_no, hist.release_no, hist.sequence_no, hist.line_item_no
from inventory_transaction_job job left join
     (select hist.*,
             MAX(dated) over (PARTITION by hist2.part_no, hist2.lot_batch_no, hist2.serial_no, hist2.location_no) as maxdated
      from inventory_transaction_hist hist
     ) hist
     on job.part_no = hist.part_no and
        job.lot_batch_no = hist.lot_batch_no and
        job.serial_no = hist.serial_no and
        job.location_no = hist.location_no join
     (SELECT hist2.order_no, hist2.lot_batch_no, hist2.serial_no, hist2.location_no, hist2.sequence_no, hist2.line_item_no
      FROM inventory_transaction_hist hist2
      ORDER BY hist2.Dated DESC
      LIMIT 1
     )
where (job.source like UPPER('%'||'&Job_No'||'%') or job.source like LOWER('%'||'&Job_No'||'%')) and
      hist.transaction LIKE '%INM-IN%' and
      hist.direction LIKE '+' and
      hist.dated = hist.maxdated
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the fast reply! I'm still getting my head around some SQL funcions but from what you have written it makes sense and is exactly what i'm after! I will give you an update when i try this out tomorrow. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help - really appreciate it!
Managed with a bit of tweaking to get it working as i would like.
If you notice anything that could be changed to improve search performance please let me know!

```
select
to_char(job.dated,'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss') date_issued,
job.userid user_id,
job.part_no,
job.quantity,
job.lot_batch_no,
job.serial_no,
job.cost,
job.quantity* job.cost total_cost,
job.source note,
to_char(hist.dated,'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss') date_PO_received,
hist.order_no,
hist.release_no,
hist.sequence_no,
hist.line_item_no

from
INVENTORY_TRANSACTION_job job
left join (select hist.*, MAX(hist.dated) over (PARTITION by hist.transaction, hist.direction, hist.part_no, hist.serial_no, hist.lot_batch_no order by hist.dated desc) as maxdated
from inventory_transaction_hist hist
) hist
on
job.part_no = hist.part_no and
job.lot_batch_no = hist.lot_batch_no and
job.serial_no = hist.serial_no and
hist.dated = hist.maxdated
where (job.source like UPPER('%'||'&Job_No'||'%') or job.source like LOWER('%'||'&Job_No'||'%'))
and hist.transaction LIKE '%INM-IN%'
and hist.direction = '+'
```

Thanks again
Jamie